# simple banner slider with text align x =center y = center, does not work

Tags: html, css, revolution-slider

i want create with revolution slider verson jquery a slider, in this slider i want compare a banner with test + background text color :
[image: example in image allegate]

if you notice the text is not center-aligned vertically

but i don't understant because in tablet and mozilla the view is good(the text is allineate x=center , y=center), while on chrome and safari not see them lined up.

i test also to change css but the result is inverse good with safari and chrome and bad with mozilla.

this is a simple code of slider

```
        <ul>
    <li data-transition="turnoff" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="600"><img alt="lightsplash24" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/trego/homepage_slider/slider5/dummy.png"}}" data-lazyload="{{media url="wysiwyg/AA-lecolart-slider-last.jpg"}}" />
    <div class="tp-caption modern_small_text_dark randomrotate" data-speed="600" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-start="1400" data-easing="easeOutExpo">
    <div class="morius">THIS IS A TEXT OF BANNER</div>
    </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

1 ) I USED before this css( with this, the result is good for mozialla but bad for chrome

```
@font-face {
    font-family: font-one;
    src: url(../fonts/Bellerose.ttf);  /* check this */
}

    .tp-caption.modern_small_text_dark{


        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
        height: 130px;

          overflow: hidden;
          border: none;
        font: normal 53px/1 "font-one", Times, serif;
          padding: 20px;
          color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
          text-align: center;
          -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          background: #111111;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;   
        vertical-align: middle;}
```

2) i used also this css (with this is good on chrome but bad in safari)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: font-one;
    src: url(../fonts/Bellerose.ttf);  /* check this */
}





.morius {
font-family: font-one;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
background: black;
font-size: 53px!important;
height: 100px;
line-height: 120%;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

how do I get a unique code that works on all browsers to have aligned text in the box black ??

as shown in this image 
[image: in this image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly remove the height. Because revolution slider will put your div's height.
2. Fixed your height by Padding.
3. No need to use overflow hidden.
4. No need to text align center.

`.tp-caption.modern_small_text_dark{
         border: none;
         font: normal 53px/1 "font-one", Times, serif;
         padding: 40px 20px;
         color: rgba(255,255,255,1); 
         background: #111111;
         -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
         box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
         text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
    }`